# How do I solve this function notation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $f(x-1)=2x^2-10x+3$, find $f(x)$. I tried the problem and received the answer $f(x)=2x^2-14x-5$, is this right?

Comment: $f(x)=f((x+1)-1)$

Comment: Whatever method you used was correct, but at the end you tried to distribute the -10 over (x+1) and made it -10x + 10 instead of -10x - 10.

Answer (score 4):

Use $x-1 = y$, hence $x = y+1$, thence

$$f(y) = 2(y+1)^2 - 10(y+1) + 3 = 2y^2 + 2 + 4y - 10y - 10 + 3$$

$$f(y) = 2y^2 - 6y - 5$$

Now just call $y = x$ and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

> $f(x)=2x^2-14x-5$ is this right?

Let's see.  $f(x-1) = 2(x-1)^2 - 14(x-1) - 5 = 2(x^2 -2x +1)-14x + 14 - 5$

$= 2x^2 - 4x +2 - 14x + 9 = 2x^2-18x +11$

No, that doesn't seem to be right.

.....

Instead try.

$x = (x+1) - 1$

Plug $(x+1)-1$ into $f$ and you get:

$f(x) = f([x+1]-1) = 2([x+1])^2 - 10([x+1]) + 3$.

$= 2(x^2+2x + 1) - 10x -10 + 3=$

$2x^2 +4x +2 - 10x -7 =$

$2x^2 - 6x -5$

[And we test it $f(x-1) = 2(x-1)^2 -6(x-1) -5 = 2x^2 -4x + 2 - 6x + 6 -5=2x^2 - 10x +3$.

]

.... But really this easiest is to say

let $x = y-1$ and so $y = x + 1$

then $f(x) = f(y-1) = 2y^2 -10y + 3$.  But $y =x+1$ so

$f(x) = f(y-1) = 2y^2 -10y + 3 = 2(x+1)^2 - 10(x+1) + 3 =$

and .... so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=2(x+1)^2-10(x+1)+3=2x^2-6x-5.$$